Account creation on Solana
Suppose I have a PDA address that hasn't been initialized yet and I send SOL to it,

Am I correct in assuming that this account will exist?
Who will have control over this account? Will it still be by program



yes
The system program is the default owner of the account however the program id used to find that PDA still has signing authority for that PDA

